# Is This a Variable or a Function? Or Both?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm following [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial) tutorial and the starter project includes a UITableViewCell class with this code:

```
var product: SKProduct? {
  didSet {
    guard let product = product else { return }

    textLabel?.text = product.localizedTitle

    if RageProducts.store.isProductPurchased(product.productIdentifier) {
      accessoryType = .checkmark
      accessoryView = nil
      detailTextLabel?.text = ""
    } else {
      ProductCell.priceFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale
      detailTextLabel?.text = ProductCell.priceFormatter.string(from: product.price)

      accessoryType = .none
      accessoryView = newBuyButton()
    }
  }
}
```

This looks like a function without parameters. I've never seen a variable with an enclosure before. The first line is a var statement but starts an enclosure:

```
var product: SKProduct? {
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Dave, Stack Overflow is not a replacement for beginners resources for learning Swift. This is covered, in detail, in the Swift Language Guide, as well as a plethora of great free resources.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov That's just not true. StackOverflow is a forum and is whatever users make it. You'll find plenty of explanations of much more basic things than this, some as simple as how to create or edit an array. More importantly, those type of questions often have x10 more views and x10 more up votes. TONS of things covered in the Swift Language Guide have been asked and happily answered here. You're really going around telling new programmers not to ask questions like "why would a variable have a function attached to it"? Just hit the back button next time and save your breath.

Comment: I wasn't saying your comment doesn't belong on SO. I'm saying that you'll have a much easier time learning Swift by going through a good beginner resource, than to pick up an advanced one and resort to SO questions to fill the holes of basic information the authors (purposely) took to be assumed knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example, `product` is a variable, and `didSet` is a function. More specifically, `didset` is a [property observer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html). From Apple's documentation:

> Property observers observe and respond to changes in a property’s value. Property observers are called every time a property’s value is set, even if the new value is the same as the property’s current value.

So the code inside of `didSet` will get executed any time you make a variable assignment, like:

```
product = someSKProduct
```

Comment: Would you mind also addressing why there's a need for that first guard statement where he then makes product = product? If that like a nil check?

Comment: @DaveG a nil check is exactly what that is. What that does is to unwrap the optional and exit early if it's `nil`.

Comment: @DaveG sure thing! Swift's optional binding is another feature of the language that's designed to reduce the amount of code you write and keep it clean. Originally, you would have written `if product != nil`, but this makes your if statement checking for the item you don't want, which isn't super readable. Next, you could do `if let product = product`, but then you'd be throwing your error logic at the bottom of this function in an `else` block, also reducing readability. `guard let product = product else { return }` keeps your code clean, readable, and handles your errors up front.

Comment: Very, very helpful. Thanks for the prompt, clear answers.